# Using Matlab's lsqcurvefit to Calculate Infinite Relaxation Spectrum

Tags: matlab

I am trying to replicate an analysis performed in a publication and am having trouble. This is about trying to calculate the infinite relaxation spectrum from rheological data.

[image: General_Function]

Given an experimental data series (above), the authors extract the relaxation spectrum (H(tau)) by solving for the difference of the sum of squares between experimental (above) and model data (below).

[image: Model]

This relaxation follows a distribution described by the following relationship.

[image: Relaxation Model]

This calculation was performed with matlabs lsqcurefit function. However, lsqcurvefit does not accept a function as a solvable parameter. I would like to know how this extraction can be accomplished using this matlab function.

EDIT: Following Bentoys comments, here is a clarification of my question.

I will detail the following just for G'' (Gdp) to save space.

I have a experimental data in the following form: a vector of frequency values (omega), xdata, and a vector of Gdp response values (Gdp).

I would like to calculate H(tau), and to do so I will need the parameters contained within that function. This gives the following expression that I need to resolve:

[image: Mix]

Gdp is a function of omega, and my xdata is a vector of omega values, but I am integrating with respect to ln(tau). This seems like it could be a possible problem?

Also, I do not have a clear ideal  of expected initial values for the 6 variables, only for the resulting H(tau), so have chosen arbitrary values to begin with. I can optimise their relative values if calculated values can be obtained.

From your suggestions my matlab code is as follows:

```
w = numdata(:,1); %w is omega (experimental xdata)
GdpExp = numdata(:,3); % response values (ydata)
x0 = [10,10,0.1,0.1,1,1]; % arbitrary intial values
H = @(x, xdata) x(1)*exp(-(xdata-log(x(3))).^2/x(5)^2/2)...
    + x(2)*exp(-(xdata-log(x(4))).^2/x(6)^2/2);

Gdp = @(A_1, A_2, tau_1, tau_2, sigma_1, sigma_2, w) ...
    integral(H([A_1, A_2, tau_1, tau_2, sigma_1, sigma_2], ...
    u).* w.*exp(u)./(1+w.^2.*exp(2*u)), -Inf, Inf);

lsqcurvefit(Gdp, x0, w, GdpExp);
```

This currenlty gives the following error:

```
>> lsqcurvefit(Gdp, x0, w, GdpExp);
Not enough input arguments.

Error in

Inf_Spec_Test>@(A_1,A_2,tau_1,tau_2,sigma_1,sigma_2,w)integral
(H([A_1,A_2,tau_1,tau_2,sigma_1,sigma_2],u).*w.*exp(u)./(1+w.^2.*exp(2*u)),
-Inf,Inf)

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 202)
        initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Caused by:
Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot 
continue.
```

Am I correct in thinking that each function is self-contained or should the naming for A_1, A_2 etc. be the same as x(1), x(2), or are the A_1 etc. simply labels to refer to the calculated values?

The experimental data and calculated H(tau) should resemble the following figures.

[image: EgFig]

I also found the following relationship, which could be used to transform the omega vector into a tau vector, which might be helpful for overcoming the discrepancy between the current xdata and the integral.

[image: EgFig]

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. With which function do you want to fit your data? If you want to fit `H` to your data, the fit procedure would search for best values of parameters (all A_i, sigma_i and tau_i), given vector of values `tau` and experimental `H`.

Comment: Hi Bentoy. From the way it is described the authors seem to be fitting the difference between the experimental and model data to extract the values of the H(taut) function. Then extracting the parameters of H(tau) afterwards, all with lsqcurvefit. This is part of the problem I am having as I do not see how to appropriatly structure the input arguments with lsqcurvefit such that I can get this result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have experimental data of `H(tau)` in the form of a vector `Y`, you want to fit your model `H`:

```
H = @(A_1, A_2, tau_1, tau_2, sigma_1, sigma_2, tau) ...
      A1*exp(-(log(tau)-log(tau_1)).^2/sigma_1^2/2) + A2*exp(-(log(tau)-log(tau_2)).^2/sigma_2^2/2);
```

`lsqcurvefit` expects a function in the form `f(x, xdata)`. Here `xdata` is the "time data", naming `tau`, and `x` all coefficients of your function. So, rewriting function `H` gives:

```
H = @(x, xdata) x(1)*exp(-(log(xdata)-log(x(3))).^2/x(5)^2/2) + x(2)*exp(-(log(xdata)-log(x(4))).^2/x(6)^2/2);
```

Then I asusme that you have some initial guess for the values of all six coefficients. If not, the fitting may not converge to the appropriate solution. I call this initial guess `x0` which is a vector of length 6. To get the fit, just call:

```
lsqcurvefit(H, x0, tau, Y)
```

You may want to add more options (such as parameter bounds), see documentation of `lsqcurvefit` for more details.

**EDIT**

Following details in comments below, you have a vector of values `G+G'` for several values of `omega` (in a vector `W`).

So the function you want to fit is a little more complex:

```
H = @(x, xdata) x(1)*exp(-(xdata-log(x(3))).^2/x(5)^2/2) + x(2)*exp(-(xdata-log(x(4))).^2/x(6)^2/2);

GGp = @(A_1, A_2, tau_1, tau_2, sigma_1, sigma_2, w) ...
      integral(H([A_1, A_2, tau_1, tau_2, sigma_1, sigma_2], u).* w.*exp(u).*(1+w.*exp(u))./(1+w.^2.*exp(2*u)), -Inf, Inf);
```

after a little change of variable, `u = ln(tau)`.

Then it is exactly the same thing, except you have now a different function to fit:

```
lsqcurvefit(GGp, x0, W, Y)
```

Comment: Hi Bentoy. Maybe I didn't explain my problem clearly. I am looking to find H(tau) by fitting the two sets of (G' + G''). One set of G' + G'' is expermental. The other contains the H(tau) that I am looking to extract. The descibed procedure appears to fit the two to each other to find values of H(tau) such that they are equal, while minimising for least sqaures. In both cases the time domain is given by the freqeuncy (omega) values. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @NzFrancis I didn't look close enough to your question! The unknown variables you want to compute are still the coefficients of the function H, right?

Comment: I am just trying to compute H(Tau) (global value series - like transforming G'(omega) into H(tau)). Right now, what I don't understand is how to extract H(tau) as it is a function. It would seem that I need to extract a value for each point on the G' + G'' data series. Furthermore, as this is an integral with respect to ln(tau) and ln(tau) is present in the H(tau) funtion I as confused by how to structure my input arguments so that I might get the desired output. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @NzFrancis Answer updated. You should not stick to the fact that you are searching a function. Since you have the analytical form of the solution, you want to compute the coefficients of this function.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, I will try this when I get back next week and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have spent a few weeks trying to play around with the advice you have provided and I think I have not adequately explained my problem (having not entirely understood exactly what I need to be asking). The following is the DOI for a paper showing what I am trying to replicate (if accessible for you?): 10.1002/adma.201605947. I should then specify that G' and G'' are currently in two separate vectors (y1 and y2). This is my experimental data. I do not have any experimental data for H(tau). I replaced the vector Y in your suggested example with either y1 or y2 vectors.

Comment: That said, I see now what you mean about finding the coefficients and ignoring the function. I believe my original question should have been "How do I structure the input arguments so that lsqcurvefit can best match them to the experimental G' and G'' data I have?" (as I was struggling with syntax) I would then be able to calculate H(tau) using these parameters and plot it. Currently, I get an error saying "not enough input arguments" using your suggested structure, even if I pull vectors of H(tau) from the exemple I am trying to replicate.

Comment: @NzFrancis Please edit your question to write down properly your problem with your new wording. Following your comments, I still believe that you are in the case n. 2. Please post your actual code and the error text associated.

Comment: Updated the question. Cheers.